# Extend JPA entity to introduce nulll object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to know if I extend and existing entity, but without adding the `@Entity` annotation on the subclass, will the subclass be an entity as well.

The reason why I want to extend the entity is to introduce a null object, and I don't want the null object to be a real entity, I don't want it to have a data base table corresponding to it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't be an entity if you don't set the `@Entity` on it.